# unpack_action_data for transfer in newer CDT version

Tags: smart-contract

in the newer version of CDT, currency is removed from eoslib.
Therefore, for `unpack_action_data<currency::transfer>()`, what value should substitute `currency::transfer`?

Answer (score 2):

(talking about version 1.3, 1.4, and maybe above)
You don't need to. Chrtistoph explains is well [here](https://cmichel.io/eos-1-3-contract-development-toolkit-updates/).

(`test` is the class name of the contract here)
In you own apply function call

```
if (code == "eosio.token"_n.value && action == "transfer"_n.value)
{
  eosio::execute_action(eosio::name(receiver), eosio::name(code), &test::transfer);
}
```

and define your own transfer function to receive the unpacked values

```
void test::transfer(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo)
{
  print("Quantity: ", quantity.amount, " with memo ", memo.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct st_transfer {
    name   from;
    name   to;
    asset  quantity;
    string memo;
};
```

I think the answer by Colin works just fine, but just in case you wanted to see how the other way works.

You would define a struct like above and use the struct to unpack incoming transfer data. This format can be used for other smartcontract actions as well.

so it looks like

unpack_action_data()